# Akka Stream - parallel processing of the source?

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I want to fetch and process multiple resources using streams. I have a list of user ids and I am traversing the list by mapping the ID to an iterator of other links.

So far it works pretty well, however can see that despite of usage of `mapAsyncUnordered` - the stream source is processed synchronously, one after another. I wonder if that happens because I use `FileIO.toPath` as sink? Or am I missing something?

The code is pretty simple:

```
import akka.stream._
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

implicit val system = ActorSystem("Local")
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors() * 4))

val src: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source[Int](Conf.startId() to Conf.endId())

val flow = Flow[Int].mapAsyncUnordered(5)(userId ⇒ Future(LikesExtractor.extractUserList(userId))(ec))
  .collect {
    case Some(Likes(self, likes)) ⇒
      likes.zip(Iterator.continually(self))
  }.mapConcat(_.toList)
  .map {
    case ((liker, likee)) ⇒ ByteString(s"${likee.username},${liker.username}\n")
  }

val f = src via flow runWith FileIO.toPath(new File(Conf.basePath()).toPath)

import concurrent.duration._
Await.ready(f, 20 minute)

sys.exit(0)
```

xref [akka-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/PjCahUJoegI)

Comment: How did you determine it's being processed serially ?

Comment: Also try adding `.async` after `collect` and last `map`.

Comment: @expert I watch the debug output that I have in `LikesExtractor`

Comment: is it possible that `LikesExtractor.extractUserList` is synchronized?